# Using a Layout with Partial Views MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, partial-views

I have an application that heavily utilises AJAX for page transitions (effectively a pseudo SPA).

The first time the application is called, it is not by AJAX, so the application will render a full view of that page (which gets the layout, all the common CSS and JS). All subsequent calls are via AJAX and the same view is rendered as a Partial view (without the layout etc)

The problem is, that even within the AJAX, there are some elements that are common. These elements must be re-rendered because the content within them is dynamic. They are defined in partial views and are included in each view so that when they are called via AJAX, they are re-rendered.

Is there a way to have a view be rendered with a different base layout when it is called from the controller? Failing that, is it possible to have a view which is called as a PartialView, still render with a Layout?

**Edit**
For clarification, Each view has a header and a footer. The header and footer contain dynamic content which needs to be updated each time the page is updated. I am currently updating using AJAX and PartialViews to save on reloading all the site level CSS, Javascript and Content. The header and footer cannot live in the main layout otherwise they would not be updated each time the page is reloaded and their content would not change.

Comment: Are you able to clarify what you're trying to achieve? I understand that it's a SPA and that you're rendering partials-within-partials, but I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

Comment: Will Edit to clarify the requirement

Comment: Can you just change the Layout for each view (or partial view)? i.e. By putting `Layout = "SomeDifferentLayout";` in each different view?

Comment: I will do some testing. They are called using `Return Partial("viewname");` and as far as i am aware, that disregards layout pages

Comment: If you specify a `Layout` in a partial, I believe it will still be used when you attempt to render the partial.

Comment: Will that override the current layout? Since the same view is called using `return View("viewname")` and `return Partial("viewname")`

Comment: You could use one Layout for general `View` returns and check for `IsAjax` for `Partial` view returns.

Comment: I have solved it by checking in ViewStart if it is an ajax request and setting the layout differently if it is. Then in the controller, i only call `Return View("viewname")`